# "Uses" vs "are using"

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, present-tense, present-continuous

When do I use "Uses" and when "are using"?

For example:

> Computers uses RAM which is faster than disk storage.

Or

> Computers are using RAM which is faster than disk storage.

The last one sounds more natural to me as a non-native English speaker,  but I also see often "uses".

When do I use which?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U jos.  I suggest you ask your question at our sister-site, http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/ for those who are learning the English language.  Regards.

Comment: I've edited your post a bit (I hope that you don't mind), but I haven't touched the examples, because that could alter the meaning of your question. However, in the first example it should be: **computers use** (subject-verb agreement) and also I think there should be a comma before 'which' in both. Without commas, these sentences mean that RAM itself is faster than disk storage, and with commas it would mean that the *use* of RAM is faster. Oh, and welcome to the ELL :-)

Comment: You don't have subject verb agreement on your first example.  "Computers use" **or** "A computer uses"

Answer (score 2):

This a matter of difference between the *Present Simple* and the *Present Continuous*.

1. Computers use *(not uses)* RAM, which is faster than disk storage. *(Notice the comma before the nonrestrictive clause)*

> I can agree that we can assume that it's one of those uncommon ways of introducing a restrictive clause using **"which"** instead of **"that"**, but the information introduced in the clause isn't necessary and doesn't specify some special kind of RAM. It is information that is nonessential to the sentence. Basically the sentence is saying, *"Computer use RAM. RAM is faster than disk storage."*

2. Computers are using RAM, which is faster than disk storage. *(This refers to a temporary action; They are using it now but generally they don't)*

Comment: The "generally they don't" reading doesn't quite work here, because of the lack of an article before "computers". The present progressive sentence means "Computers today use RAM (but they didn't **before**)." Whereas the simple present sentence means "Computers use RAM (and that's an inherent part a computer)." Since the computers we know have more or less always used RAM, I wouldn't use the present progressive at all. (However, I *would* use it to say: "Computers are using DDR4 RAM nowadays.")

Answer (score 0):

> Computers use RAM

is correct and indicates that computers use RAM *habitually, all the time, everyday*.

> Computers are using RAM

indicates something that is happening *right now* but is likely only temporary.

To use another example: "I eat meat" tells you that I am not a vegetarian. "I am eating meat" tells you that *right now* I am sitting at a table chewing bacon, but 30 minutes from now I probably won't be eating bacon.